# No Form Library App Option to Add in Publishing Site

Tags: form

I created a Publishing Site in SharePoint 2013 but I can't create a Form Library.  The app option doesn't exist.  I enabled Enterprise Features. What else could I be missing?

Bismarck

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to turn on the Team Collaboration Lists Site(Web level) Feature.

That's the one that enables Form Libraries.

It is turned off by default when using some of the Publishing Site templates.

Comment: That was it.  It didn't seem obvious to me that is what was needed.  Thanks.

Comment: If it worked for your question, I would appreciate a vote up or you mark it as the accepted answer.